# Jscrollpane set vertical scrollbar track height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jscrollpane

I'm trying to set a static height of a vertical scrollbar in the jscrollpane library. I have tried settings the track height via CSS and that did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jscrollpane has a `verticalTrackHeight` settings variable, but it cannot be set by the user. The only way I've determined to do it is to modify the library slightly:

Within the `initialiseVerticalScroll` method change the following line from:

```
verticalTrackHeight = paneHeight;
```

To:

```
if(typeof settings.verticalTrackHeight === "number") {
    verticalTrackHeight = settings.verticalTrackHeight;
} else {
    verticalTrackHeight = paneHeight;
}
```

The height of the vertical track now be set via settings.